# Cumulative distrbution function of variables that define the angle and the length in a unit circle.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

So I am trying to do this past term exam from my institution:

> We pick a random point $M$ in the unit circle. Picking any point has the same probability. We define $X$ as the length from the center to $M$, and $Y$ the angle. What is the cumulative distribution fonction of $X$? Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. And calcule their probability density function.

My attempt:

So if $X \leq t$ for a $t \in [0,1]$ then that means that all the points $(x,y)$ in the unit circle such that their length from the center is smaller than $t$, which can expressed as $x^2 + y^2 \leq t$. I first need to calculate the volume of the unit circle, I get:
 $$\int _{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}rdrd\theta = \pi $$

Now then $$F_X(t) = P(X \leq t) =\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{t}rdrd\theta$$ $$= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} (\frac{t^2}{2})d\theta = \frac{t^2}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta = t^2$$

Now to show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, I can show that $F_{X,Y}(t, \psi) = F_X(t)F_Y(\psi)$ .

So I have $$(1) \text{  }F_{X,Y}(t, \psi) = \frac{1}{\pi } \int_{0}^{\psi}\int_{0}^{t}rdrd\theta = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\psi}d\theta \int_{0}^{t}rdr = \frac{\psi t^2}{2\pi} $$
By Fubini-Tonelli. As $$F_Y(\psi) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \psi $$ We have:  $$F_{X,Y}(t, \psi) =F_X(t)F_Y(\psi) $$ 
Thus the two variables are independent.

Now, their density function are $$\frac{dF_x(t)}{dt}= 2t $$ and $$\frac{dF_Y(\psi)}{dt} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \mathbb{1}_{[0,2\pi]}(\psi)$$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: by calculation of CDF of $X$ we are dealing with $r^2=x^2+y^2\leq t^2$ so that $0\leq r\leq t$ and not $0\leq r\leq t^2$ as you state.

Comment: @drhab I missed that! I made the appropriate edit, is it correct now?

Comment: It looks okay to me, but an expression for the *joint* PDF lacks. That will be the product of the PDF's of $X$ and $Y$ because they are independent.

Comment: @drhab Isn't the $(1)$ expression for the joint PDF?

Comment: No. That is the joint CDF.